# Uncaught exception: Attempting to call a function in a renderer window that has been closed or released

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron, ipc

I'm new to desktop application development and am using Electron with node.js and javascript to build my app. Here is a short description of what I'm trying to achieve:

- FirstWindow.html

  has list of products with each list item associated with event listener double click. On double clicking any element.
- SecondWindow.html

  is supposed to be created which has the information of clicked product which is fetched from the database (postgesql). But on opening the app I get the following error:

> **Uncaught Exception: Attempting to call a function in a renderer window that has been closed or released**

Here is my code snippet where I've tried to implement ipcMain and ipcRenderer modules:

**main.js**

```
const electron = require('electron');
ipcMain.on('item_catch_in_main', function(e, productname){
  SecondWindow.webContents.send('item_action_to_be_done', productname);
});
```

**FirstWindow.html**

```
<script>
const { ipcRenderer } = require('electron');
ipcRenderer.send('item_catch_in_main', productname);
</script>
```

**SecondWindow.html**

```
<script>
const { ipcRenderer } = require('electron');
ipcRenderer.on('item_action_to_be_done', (event, item) => {
console.log(item);
});
</script>
```

Please let me know if anyone has worked around similar problem in Elecrton. Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's an old post, but did you ever find a solution for this?